# Can Java Netbeans desktop application and Maven work together?

Tags: java, maven, desktop-application, netbeans-8

I have developed a java desktop application in netbeans 8.1 for a security project I am currently busy with.

I have been asked by the client to add Google drive or DropBox to the desktop application for storing the data files on the cloud storage at any of the two mentioned above.

I have done research and have seen that the only way to get this to work is to use Maven or Gradle.
I have picked up that there is Maven projects in Netbeans, But I would like to know if the following is possible:

- Would it be possible to just copy the desktop application to the Maven created project?
- Do I need to use the dependencies to add the jars needed for the desktop application classes?
- Will I need to re-download the jar files or how can I add the jars that I currently have on the computer to the Maven project?
- Will the copying of the normal desktop application to the maven project affect any of the other features created previously?
- Does the Maven project work differently from normal java desktop applications created in Netbeans?

I would be very grateful for answers to this or any other information that would help out. I do not want to start this transition and land up it not working out.

Any information will be tremendously helpful.

Much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0):

At work here, most java developers use netbeans with Maven.
Netbeans for java is built around Maven.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That will help, so you saying that it will be suitable to just copy the desktop app I created into the Maven created project and everything will work as normal. No need to do a lot of alternations in order to get it to work.. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can import a project by using the pom.xml file

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Does this mean that the entire desktop app I previously created will be fully imported into the maven project and just work of that or will it mean running two different projects together to app function. Sorry about asking all the questions, but I just have not worked with Maven or in this manner yet. Thanks for you help and time.